# Is it possible to get average Berkeley DB record size

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm using db_stat to get approximate number of records in the BDB (to avoid iteration over the whole database):

```
[me@home magic]$ db_stat -d random.db
Thu Mar  3 13:38:25 2016        Local time
61561   Hash magic number
8       Hash version number
Little-endian   Byte order
        Flags
643     Number of pages in the database
4096    Underlying database page size
0       Specified fill factor
2340    Number of keys in the database
2340    Number of data items in the database
299     Number of hash buckets
303540  Number of bytes free on bucket pages (75% ff)
15      Number of overflow pages
39282   Number of bytes free in overflow pages (36% ff)
114     Number of bucket overflow pages
322730  Number of bytes free in bucket overflow pages (30% ff)
0       Number of duplicate pages
0       Number of bytes free in duplicate pages (0% ff)
1       Number of pages on the free list
```

Is it possible to get average record size as well?

I guess I can use following info to get overall size:

```
643     Number of pages in the database
4096    Underlying database page size
```

643*4096 = 2633728 Bytes (corresponds with the file size) and get approximate record size 2633728/2340 = 1125

So my question - would using additional info from db_stat info give me more accurate result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've computed the **upper bound** on average record size:

```
643 pages * 4096 bytes / page = 2633728 bytes total
2633728 bytes / 2340 keys (records) = 1126 bytes / record
```

You can get closer to the truth by **subtracting all the "bytes free on XXX pages" from the total**.  This is space that's not in use by the database because of inefficiencies in how it was populated.  (As an aside, this doesn't look too bad, but whenever there are a significant number of overflow pages, you could consider a larger page size.  Of course, there are downsides to larger page sizes too.  Yay, databases!)

```
 2633728 bytes 
- 303540 bytes free on bucket pages
-  39282 bytes free in overflow pages
- 322730 bytes free in bucket overflow pages
-      0 bytes free in duplicate pages
--------
 1968176 bytes total / 2340 keys = 841 bytes / record
```

This figure still isn't really the average record size, but I think it's as close as you can get from `db_stat`.  It includes the supporting database structure for each record, and other database overhead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: I can't find anything that specifically describes what you're looking for.  The concept of overflow pages of various types, and how pages are used in a database can be treated generally.  So, you might find some answers in a database textbook like Gray and Reuter's _Transaction Processing_.